# Protecting a finished wood exterior door

Tags: doors, exterior, finishing

I have a solid wood exterior door, that I had stained and finished by the maker.  I was looking for a way to prolong and protect the finish.  I thought about waxing the door (especially the exterior side).  Any have any suggestions on this ?  I thought just a spray automotive wax would do the trick.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but auto wax sounds like the wrong thing. Think porosity, metal vs wood. I'd wait for a good answer. If there isn't a answer on this by this time tmw, I'll my contractor buddy.

Comment: "*stained and **finished** by the maker*" What exactly did the finishing entail (ask the manufacturer)? If it's stained it should be fine. Don't use automative wax. To be honest I can't think why you would think to use automative wax, its for metal not wood. [further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_finishing#Comparison_of_different_clear_finishes)

Comment: I was thinking of the auto wax cause thats what the SalesPerson mentioned. I wasn't sure on it so I figured I would ask here.

Answer (score 3):

You mention the door is "finished" by the manufacturer. Can you tell me what type of finish ? Most exterior doors that are stained can be sealed with a product such as spar varnish, or marine grade epoxy. Seikens makes some very good marine sealers that work great on exterior wood doors exposed to direct sunlight. If your door is shaded and protected by a storm door, than  it can be sealed with urethane, however urethane is not recommended for direct exposure to the elements or direct sunlight.

Comment: I am going to contact the manufacturer to find out what explain the finish. The door is on the north side of the property and recessed a couple feet so it doesn't get a lot of direct sunlight. Humidity is high though, being in Houston.

Comment: After you find out from the manufacturer what is on there over the stain, you can decide. Ask them if a poly overcoat will be compatible with their final finish. I would go with urethane as long as it doesn't get hit with a lot of water, ie: rain. Being on the north side, you won't have to worry about UV on the urethane. I have used urethane on many north facing doors , however they are protected by a storm door.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a automotive, paste wax, especially one that contains a LARGE amount of natural waxes, i.e. carnauba !     ( "Blue Coral" )

Follow application instructions on can ....